# How to get File Explorer to skip all existing files when copying?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

When copying files from a PC to an Android phone, Windows 10 would bring up the prompt below.

If I check the 'Do this for all conflicts' and click on 'Don't copy', the whole copy operation stops and Explorer doesn't try to copy the non existing files. Is this a bug?
It seems it works if I click on Don't copy one file at a time but this is very time consuming when copying thousands of files.

How can I get it to copy all nonexisting files in a single action?
I don't want to use any command line utilities like Robocopy. Prefer GUI ones.

[image]

Comment: In Robocopy, built into Windows, it's easy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935583/how-to-skip-existing-and-or-same-size-files-when-using-robocopy

Answer (score 0):

I used a wifi ftp server on the phone and Directory Opus on the PC and Opus skips existing files during the ftp transfer.